# Error running simulation — An unknown error occurred

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

```
{
    "__name__":"/databases/(default)/documents/users/mfBBtfSX91YS9mXrkmEDTksA0712/sold/mfBBtfSX91YS9mXrkmEDTksA0712-hanSW0s5MxOOENWnc5T1cLinekj2/invoice/WhdEi2W83GtjDjowi6MV",
  "id":"WhdEi2W83GtjDjowi6MV",
  "data":{
    "id":"db1a01a0-4da5-11ec-a579-c31f34aa6119",
    "total":80,
    "quotations":[
    {
      "id":"c595e610-46ab-11ec-b8ad-d56159e1778c",
      "title":"anda",
      "measuremntUnit":"kg",
      "rate":35,
      "quantity":2,
      "isSelected":false,
      "index":1
    },
    {
      "id":"c595e610-46ab-11ec-b8ad-d56159e1778c",
      "title":"biscuit",
      "measuremntUnit":"packet",
      "rate":10,
      "quantity":1,
      "isSelected":true,
      "index":7}
      ],
    "sellerEmail":"ku1438693@gmail.com",
    "sellerUserId":"mfBBtfSX91YS9mXrkmEDTksA0712",
    "sellerDisplayName":" Lila Kunwar",
    "buyerUserId":"hanSW0s5MxOOENWnc5T1cLinekj2",
    "buyerDisplayName":"saugat thapa",
    "buyerEmail":"nexus.saugat26@gmail.com",
    "sellerPhotoUrl":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AATXAJ",
    "buyerPhotUrl":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AATXAJ"
  }}
```

i am trying to check whether above data can insert into firestore given that the following is the security rule. however i get error `Error running simulation — An unknown error occurred`.

```
 match /users/{userId}{
     
    match /sold/{soldId}/{document=**}{
                function isAuthed(){
        return request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
    function isSeller(){
        return   request.auth.uid == resource.data.sellerUserId || 
                request.auth.uid == resource.data.buyerUserId;
    }
     function isApproved() {
        return request.resource.data.isApproved == false;
            // || request.resource.data.reviewed == "false"
      }
      function quotations(){
          return request.resource.data.quotations;
      }
      function isOtherThanQuotations(){
          return 
          isValidStringInput(request.resource.data.buyerUserId) &&
          isValidStringInput(request.resource.data.buyerEmail) &&
          isValidStringInput(request.resource.data.buyerPhotoUrl) &&
          isValidStringInput(request.resource.data.buyerDisplayName) &&
          isValidStringInput(request.resource.data.sellerUserId)&&
          isValidStringInput(request.resource.data.buyerEmail) &&
          isValidStringInput(request.resource.data.buyerPhotoUrl) &&
          isValidStringInput(request.resource.data.buyerDisplayName) &&
          isValidNumber(request.resource.data.total) &&
          // isApproved() &&
          request.resource.data.createdAt == request.time;
          
      }
      function isSelected() {
        return request.resource.data.isSelected == false;
            // || request.resource.data.reviewed == "false"
      }
      function isValidQuotation(item) {
        return quotations()[item].keys().hasAll(
            [
                'title',
                'rate',
                'quantity',
                'measuremntUnit',
                'isSelected',
                'index',
                ])
        && isValidStringInput(quotations()[item].title, 200)
        && isValidNumber(quotations()[item].rate)
        && isValidNumber(quotations()[item].quantity)
        
        && isValidStringInput(quotations()[item].measuremntUnit, 200)
        && isValidNumber(quotations()[item].index)
        && isSelected();
       
        
      }
      

      function isValidStringInput(input, maxSize) {
        return input is string
            && input.size() > 0
            && input.size() <= maxSize;
      }
       function isValidNumber(input) {
        return input is int
            || input.matches('^[0-9]+$');
      }
    allow read: if isSeller();
    allow write: if isAuthed() 
         
        && quotations().size() >= 1
        && quotations().size() <= 10
        
        && isOtherThanQuotations()
        
        && isValidQuotation(0)
        && (quotations().size() < 2 || isValidquotation(1) )
        
        && (quotations().size() < 3 || isValidquotation(2) )
        
        && (quotations().size() < 4 || isValidquotation(3) )
        
        && (quotations().size() < 5 || isValidquotation(4) )
        
        && (quotations().size() < 6 || isValidquotation(5) )
        && (quotations().size() < 7 || isValidquotation(6) )
        && (quotations().size() < 8 || isValidquotation(7) )
        && (quotations().size() < 9 || isValidquotation(8) )
        && (quotations().size() < 10 || isValidquotation(9) )
        && (quotations().size() < 11 || isValidquotation(10) );
        
        
       
    } 
    }
```

is it becase i have too too many functions? right now myconcern is with create only.
is it becasue the `id` doesnt  have security rule to validate? i tried providing validation for id as well but the error still persist. i need more than 10 map in an array but this is for simplicity of testing process.

Comment: Where do you get the error `Error running simulation — An unknown error occurred`? In you app or in firebase console?

Comment: @RafaelJan firebase console. i found the syntax error at "isValidquotation" which must be "isValidQuotation" and used isSelected() for map which should access map but access like a field of the document. i was able to do so using emulator of firebase where log tab shows teh warning for the mistakes. and i also used one line at a time to figure out hwo to make the security rule work.

Comment: @Saugat Thapa Is your issue resolved?

Comment: I copied your security rule and tried it in Firebase Console -> Firestore Databse -> Rules, everything works fine and it publishes without any errors(syntax errors or warnings). Just in addition to your rules, I added the rules_version=2 and service cloud.firestore{ } in the first two lines. Did you add rules_version =2, service cloud.firestore at the first two lines of the rules? If you did not add that, you will receive errors and warnings. Please confirm.

Comment: @PriyashreeBhadra yes my issue is resolved. i took help form emulator.

Comment: Okay great. Please post your solution as an answer for community help.

Comment: What was it that caused the problem?