# Firestore Security Rules: Error running simulation –An unknown error occurred

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

[image: Screenshot from the Firebase Console with the error]

These are my security rules for Cloud Firestore:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /Feedback/{feedback} {
       allow read: if resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid;
    }
  }
}
```

It appears that I have a weird bug. When I try to access the documents in the "Feedback" collection, I get with my client a "permissioned denied" error. Using the Firestore Security Rules Playground, I get "Firestore Security Rules: Error running simulation –An unknown error occurred". I don't see where the issue with the security rules is.

I don't see any logs in my browser console. Already disabled uBlock Origin.

If I only use `allow read: if request.auth.uid != null` it works. However, I do something with `resouce.data` it throws an unknown error.

I already had a look into [Error running simulation — An unknown error occurred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70106164/error-running-simulation-an-unknown-error-occurred). However, there is no solution to the problem.

Comment: Even copying the example from the Firestore docs (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation) produces the same error...

Comment: please verify that the doc `feedback` has field `uid` and it is correct  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*firebaser here*

Our console engineering team has confirmed the issue, and is rolling back a recent change.

- March 6, 9:42AM PT: We've only seen reports of this affecting the rules playground. No other access (such as from SDKs) seems to be affected.
- March 6, 10:40AM PT: Our console engineering team has confirmed the issue, and is rolling back a recent change.
- March 7, 6:30AM PT: The engineering is rollout out a fix today.

Comment: Still experiencing this issue when using `request.auth.uid == resource.data.user1Uid`

Answer (score 1):

I think it has something to do with default database being null. It says "/databases/null/documents" under "Rules Playground" title.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the `resource.data.uid` is null.
I'm going through the same but instead getting the error "The path ... is improperly formatted. Paths should start with `"/databases/$(database)/documents/"`.
I think @umd is right, we are not pointing to the DB correctly, but have no idea how to change that null in the Location.

**Mar 8: Firebase rolled out a fix for it**